# Passar dados por contexto (HOC) React

Tags: javascript, react

Boas, estou a fazer um sistema de formulários em react. Estou a usar o contexto para passar algumas informações para os componentes filhos. A estrutura do projeto é a seguinte:

**/context** - Onde tenho guardado o contexto

```
import React from "react";
const FormContext = React.createContext();
export { FormContext };
```

**/Form.js** - Componente principal

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FormContext } from "./context/index";

export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <FormContext.Provider values={{ value: "teste" }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </FormContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

withFormContext.js - HOC para passar o contexto

```
import React from "react";
import { FormContext } from "../context/index";
const withFormContext = Component => (
  <FormContext.Consumer>
    {({ controller }) => <Component controller={controller} {...this.props} />}
  </FormContext.Consumer>
);

export default withFormContext;
```

**/TextInput.js** - Elemento de texto do formulário

```
import React from "react";
import { withFormContext } from "../HOC/withFormContext";

const TextInput = ({ ...props }) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <input type="text" />;
};
export default withFormContext(TextInput);
```

**App.js** - Componente que vai chamar o form

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Form from "./libs/forms/Form";
import TextInput from "./libs/forms/components/TextInput";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Form nameForm="xxxxx">
          <TextInput />
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Acontece é que não consigo passar as propriedades para o componente **TextInput.js** através do HOC. Será que me podem ajudar ou na vossa opinião o que devo usar neste tipo de situações?